# hook_theme() affects display order of a node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a node with many CCK fields. I want to hide a field from anonymous user. I found there are roughly two approaches from http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-5-and-6. First, I tried theme_theme() with the code below

```
function ssaa_theme1(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'volunteer_node_form' => array(
            'arguments' => array('form' => null),
        ),
    );
}


function ssaa_volunteer_node_form($form) {
    $out = '';
    if (user_is_anonymous()) {
        unset($form['field_active']);
    }
    $out .= drupal_render($form);
    return $out;
}
```

This simple code worked well as I expected but produced strange result too. Save/Preview buttons are appeared on the top of the form and I couldn't move them to the bottom. At first I suspected drupal_render() function but it didn't do anything about the order. It produced same result when ssaa_volunteer_node_form() function was empty.

So I tried second option which uses hook_form_alter() and succeeded. But I still want to figure out why first approach didn't work properly. I think it's more easy and light way to do what I want to do.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to deny this one field to users, it makes sense to form_alter it. Otherwise, I also suggest you use Content Permissions. It will give you the power to toggle such settings for all your fields without needing a text editor.

CCK Field input forms do not accept `hook_form_alter()` very well. They are inserted into the node edit form late in the cycle, so to speak.

[This example](http://drupal.org/node/357328) demonstrates how disable CCK form elements, it can be adapted to suit your needs.

As you have a very specific need, you might want to look at the new [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. It is still in development (**and I have not tried it**), but it allows you to opt-in individual fields to Content Permissions. This prevents your Permissions screen from getting cluttered and from all new fields defaulting to inaccessible.

Comment: Wow I wasn't aware of that Field Permissions module. It sounds like some of the benefits like "Edit own field permission" seem pretty worth it.

Comment: With Field Permissions module you suggested, it accomplished perfectly. That CCK field's default value also works. I really need the default value working. I've tried Content Permissions module but there're so many checkboxes to be checked (There're nearly 20 content types and 8 roles in the system) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the Content Permissions module that comes bundled with CCK to set field-level permissions. Once you enable that module, all of your fields will appear in the Permissions area and you can deny permission to anonymous users there. I think that would be a much easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: I tried Content Permissions module before, but I gave up checking hundreds of checkboxes though. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in Drupal 6 recently, and your question is valid.

When I displayed the $form object (from *template.php*) using [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel)'s dsm() function, I found that the buttons were somehow showing a weight of 0.0111, a float.

The **hook_theme()** and then **hook_form()** in *template.php* seem to be behaving wrong.
Using hook_form I made no changes to the $form object, and returning drupal_render($form)  the Save/Preview buttons were at the top.

To anyone that needs to use these hooks, you must ALSO create a **form_alter** where you set the weight of the buttons. This counteracts the bug and gets your buttons to the bottom again.

```
    $form['buttons']['#weight'] = 100;
```

Note: I could not set the weight in my **hook_form()** code, it had to be in a **form_alter**